# Which preposition would you use in this case?

Tags: prepositions

I have two choices at work. Both are good for me, so I just need to ask if there's a preferable option for the company.
Should my question be:
"Is there any difference **for** the company" or "**to** the company"?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Emily, welcome to English Language & Usage. The "for" and "to" prepositions are roughly equivalent and depend on your context, so I wouldn't fret over which one to use. Personally, this (AmE) speaker has a slight preference for "for." I'm going to recommend moving your question to our sister site, ELL.

Comment: @rajah9 How are they "roughly equivalent," and why the "preference for *for* ?"

Comment: ELL is here: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I really can't say because there's a dearth of context. It depends on what you're asking. Contrived example. Perhaps someone has just told the CEO, "We're taking away free coffee." Case A. "Really? Is there any difference for the company?" "Yes, your programmers will quit." Case B. "Really? Is there any difference to the company?" "Yes, you'll save $3,000 per month."

Answer (score 0):

*To* and *for* have many meanings.

*X for Y* can express allocation, e.g. something is a resource that X uses or will use.

*X to Y* can express targeting, e.g. X is an activity that when completed, changes/modifies/involves/concerns the state of Y.

In this case since both meanings overlap, you can use either one.